# Large file and hashing - performance concern

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to hash a file (16 MB) line by line with the following code :

```
 def hash(data, protocol) do
   :crypto.hash(protocol, data)
   |> Base.encode16()
 end

 File.stream!(path)
 |> Stream.map(&hash(&1, :md5) <> "h")
 |> Enum.to_list()
 |> hd()
 |> IO.puts()
```

According to `time` command, this takes between 10 to 12 seconds, which seems to be a huge number to, me considering that with the following Python code :

```
import md5

with open('a', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    l = []
    for _, val in enumerate(content):
        m = md5.new()
        m.update(val)
        l.append(m.hexdigest() + "h")

    print l[0]
```

runs (still according to `time`) in about 2.3 seconds.

Where would I stard to improve the performance of my Elixir code ? I tried to to split the initial stream into 10 chunks, and fire an asynchronous task for each of them :

```
File.stream!(path)
|> Stream.chunk(chunk_size) # with chunk_size being (nb_of_lines_in_file / 10)
|> Enum.map(fn chunk -> Task.async(fn -> Enum.map(chunk, &hash(&1, :md5) <> "h") end) end)
|> Enum.flat_map(&Task.await/1)
|> hd()
|> IO.puts()
```

but it yields even or worse results, about 11+ seconds to run, why is that ?

Comment: 1) How does the performance of the first one differ if you remove the hashing line? 2) And what if you change your definition of `hash` so that it mirrors what you do in the second example? 3) Your code doesn't use the hash at all, so it would be permissible to optimize out the whole loop body. While python might not be able to take advantage of that, it's still good practice to ensure that the result of computations gets actually used.

Comment: About 3),  I updated the three codes and their respective runtime in my question so they all make use of the hashes by appending a character to them, and printing the first hashed line at the end. About 1), there is indeed a huge perf boost for my first code without the hashing, it runs in about 4s.

Comment: 4) The first uses `crypto.hash` the second uses `md5` directly. Is that responsible for the performance difference? 5) How long are your lines on averabe?

Comment: 4) sorry for the confusion , the second example references the hash function defined in the first example. 5) from 3 to 15 characters max I would say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to take into account is that using time to record the performance of Elixir code is always going to take into account 
the start up time of the BEAM virtual machine. Depending on your 
application, it may or may not make sense to include this in any
comparision benchmarks to other languages. If you just want to 
maximize the performance of Elixir code, it's best to use a benchmarking 
tool like Benchfella or even just :timer.tc from erlang.

https://hex.pm/packages/benchfella

My guess is that your performance problems are all I/O related. 
`File.stream!` is not particularly efficient for line processing of large files.

I wrote a blog post on a similar problem of hashing the entire file.

http://www.cursingthedarkness.com/2015/06/micro-benchmarking-in-elixir-using.html

And there is a slide talk about doing fast line based processing here.

http://bbense.github.io/beatwc/

I think if you slurp the whole file in you'll get better performance. I would not hesitate at all to just use

```
File.stream!(path) |> Enum.map(fn(line) -> hash(line, :md5) <> "h" end )
```

for a 16mb file. Using a Stream in a pipeline almost always trades speed for memory use. Since data is immutable in Elixir, large lists generally have less overhead than you would initially expect.

Your task based code won't help much since I suspect the majority of the 
time is spent in chunking the lines in these two lines.

```
File.stream!(path)
|> Stream.chunk(chunk_size) # with chunk_size being (nb_of_lines_in_file / 10)
```

That's going to be really slow. Another code example you might find useful. 
https://github.com/dimroc/etl-language-comparison/tree/master/elixir

There are a lot of tricks you can use to get fast file processing in Elixir. You can often improve the speed from the naive `File.stream!` version by multiple orders of magnitude.

Comment: Great answer. It is worth pointing out that it may be even faster by just loading the whole file into memory. Those abstractions are great when working with really large collections or files, for small ones, it just really adds overhead.

Comment: I tested File.stream! |> Enum.to_list vs reading in the whole file and then using binary.split and for a 28 meg, 1000_000 line file the runtime is similar.For this problem, I/O time is the only real constraint, unless the lines are much longer than in a typical text file.